# Is it possible to change tags that are not writable by exiftool?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, exif, exiftool

I have a (Dolby Vision) video file `test.mp4` but has `hev1` in video track `Codec ID` (ffmpeg) or `Compressor ID` (exiftool)

```
exiftool -CompatibleBrands -CompressorID test.mp4
Compatible Brands               : isom, dby1, iso2, mp41
Compressor ID                   : hev1
```

While I run `exiftool -CompatibleBrands=isom -CompressorID=dvhe` it shows

```
Warning: Sorry, CompatibleBrands is not writable
Warning: Sorry, CompressorID is not writable
Nothing to do.
```

The video stream has `HDR format : Dolby Vision, Version 1.0, dvhe.05.07, BL+RPU` in mediainfo, so it should be dvhe.

I have also tried `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -map 0 -codec copy -brand dvhe -strict experimental test2.mp4`, but hev1 is still there.

`perl -pi -e 's/hev1/dvhe/g' test.mp4` partially works, but it also changes `Format` and overall `Codec ID` to `dvhe` (`Codec ID` is `dvhe (dvhe/dby1/iso2/mp41)`)

Is it possible to change the two (and other unwritable) sections?

Answer (score 0):

`CompressorID`
is a
[QuickTime ImageDesc Tag](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html#ImageDesc),
while `CompatibleBrands` is a
[QuickTime FileType Tag](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html#FileType).

These tags are not writable, because they are essential for
playing this media.
You can't change these tags, at least not with ExifTool.
It might be possible with some video editing
program, but I can't recommend any such editor.

To change these tags safely, the easiest method is to re-encode
the media file.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** change these tags with ExifTool in theory. But you need to redefine its [config](https://exiftool.org/config.html) for that and override tag definitions there, changing their `Writable` type to `string`. Examples can be found under `%Image::ExifTool::UserDefined` section in the above example, e.g.:

```
%Image::ExifTool::UserDefined = (
    'Image::ExifTool::Exif::Main' => {
        0xd000 => {
            Name => 'NewEXIFTag',
            Writable => 'int16u',
            WriteGroup => 'IFD0',
        },
    },
);
```

Config data needs to be adapted for your tags according to e.g. tables [here](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html) or in [source code](https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool/blob/f7931c28a413acfbb326ba94af86d6e6845add9c/lib/Image/ExifTool/QuickTime.pm#L854).

Now, should you mess with that and attempt to change these tags? You could for testing on a backed up file of course, but it'll very likely be a **waste of time**. Even if it lets you edit them in the end (according to @StarGeek it **won't**), the names of the tags clearly suggest something that should not be manually tinkered with, like device/software compatibility.

This looks like a clear XY problem and I would recommend instead asking about your main goal.

Comment: [This Exiftool forum's post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=14874.msg80852#msg80852) gives an example of a config for video tags.  But since none of the tags in the groups these tags belong to (see @harrymc post) that exiftool doesn't have the ability to write in that part of the file.